# Drawing a 100x100 contour plot depicting R2 (Rsquared) values using R

Tags: r, plot, contour

I have a remote sensing data set consisting of 106 columns and 28 rows. The rows relate to individual observations, or individual plots in my instance. The first column stores the uniqueID by which each plot may be identified. The next 100 columns store the average measured reflectance values for each plot in consecutive spectral bands (band_x, band_x2, band_x3, etc.). The remaining 5 columns store the values of various plant parameters (e.g. chlorophyll, nitrogen, biomass, etc.) that were measured in the field for each plot. The data set just more or less looks as follows:

```
PlotID    b1     b2    ....    b99    b100    biomass    nitrogen
1         0.11   0.16          0.40   0.41    10         52
2         0.09   0.11          0.41   0.40    19         35
3         0.10   0.19          0.43   0.49    18         72
4         0.13   0.10          0.44   0.39    16         46
...
```

I'm looking to create contour plots that depict R2 (Rsquared) values for all possible correlations for all possible combinations of two bands that are correlated to a single plant parameter (e.g. biomass). For example, the contour plots need to present the R2 values for the correlation between all possible simple ratio combinations (band_x1/band_x2) and a single trait. Besides, I am looking to replicate this for two other type of indices, being a normalized difference index ((band_x2+band_x1)/(band_x2-band_x1)) and a simple difference index (band_x2-band_x1).

I have been looking at the contour.plot syntax in R and various practical examples, however, none does in anyway relate to what I am after. I have seen these graphs before, so there must be a way of generating them. Who can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: to clarify some things, here is an example of a graph that I am looking for to recreate: 
http://image.slidesharecdn.com/2269e63a-1825-41b1-8d58-6901fd5b56ba-150102021118-conversion-gate01/95/thenkabailuavgermanyfinal1b-46-638.jpg?cb=1420186425

Using the help of Heroka, I have by now managed to recreate most of the plot, based on the following code (the majority of the code, however, is mostly related to graphics):

```
n_band=101
dat <- read.table("C:\\data.txt", header=TRUE)
res <- expand.grid(paste0("b", seq(from = 450, to = 950, by =   5)),paste0("b",seq(from = 450, to = 950, by = 5)),outcome=c("nitrogen"))

res$R2 <- apply(res, MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x){
return(cor(dat[,x[1]]/dat[,x[2]],dat[,x[3]])^2)
})

library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(res, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=R2)) +
geom_tile() +
facet_grid(~outcome)
p1 +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=+90)) +
geom_vline(xintercept=c(seq(from = 1, to = 101, by = 5)),color="#8C8C8C") +
geom_hline(yintercept=c(seq(from = 1, to = 101, by = 5)),color="#8C8C8C") +
labs(list(title = "Contour plot of R^2 values for all possible correlations  between Simple Ratio indices & Nitrogen Content", x = "Wavelength 1 (nm)", y = "Wavelength 2 (nm)")) +
scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("b450","b475","b500","b525","b550","b575","b600","b625","b650","b675","b700","b725","b750","b775","b800","b825","b850","b875","b900","b925","b950")) +
scale_y_discrete(breaks = c("b450","b475","b500","b525","b550","b575","b600","b625","b650","b675","b700","b725","b750","b775","b800","b825","b850","b875","b900","b925","b950")) +
scale_fill_continuous(low = "black", high = "green")
```

[ContourPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VpDT.png)
I am getting quiet near to my ultimate goal, but a few things remain that I would like to change:
- Have a scale bar in discrete colors, preferably relying on a vastly diverse but gradual color scheme to better allow identification of the band combinations with highest R2 values. I would ideally like to use a standard number of classes (8), each comprising of the same number of observations, for all plots. Hereby allowing the software itself to determine the break values, based on the min and max R2 values for each parameter being correlated.
- Besides, I would like to be able to identify the highest values from each the plot, or more specifically their (x,y) coordinates so I can tell which bands produce highest correlations. I have used which.min and which.max, but they yield no sensible results nor (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Calculating the correlations or creating the plot? Your question is very broad.

Comment: I guess the answer to your questions is: both. All I have now is the data frame as mentioned above. I want to eventually arrive at a contour plot with R2 values, but have truly no idea how to get there from where I am at now.

Comment: Continued: ...
I reckon I first have to devise a way to create a matrix/vector consisting of 10.000 (100 x 100) lists, storing the index values for each of the 28 plots, for each possible index. Perhaps, once I have arrived at such a data set, drawing of the contour plot might be more straight forward. But I honestly don't know if I'm on the right track

Comment: For your convenience and to hopefully help in indicating what I am eventually after, here is a screenshot of what the output should ideally look like: http://image.slidesharecdn.com/2269e63a-1825-41b1-8d58-6901fd5b56ba-150102021118-conversion-gate01/95/thenkabailuavgermanyfinal1b-46-638.jpg?cb=1420186425

Comment: How would you calculate R2 for one combination of bands and one outcome (like biomass?)

Comment: Each column contains 28 values, such as 28 index values or 28 values for a distinct parameter (e.g. biomass). The R2 is thus derived from a correlation between all 28 index values and the 28 parameter values.

Comment: I understand that. I'm trying to convey to you that SO is not a code-writing service, and that it's at least worth it (with some help) to try to solve your own problem instead of someone else writing your code for you. So, the first step here is: how to get R2 for one combination of bands and one outcome. The next step is to expand this to all combinations of bands.

Comment: However, I thus first need to arrive at a (100 x 100) data set where each 'cell' stores 28 index values for each possible combination of bands, i.e. each cell represents a list of some sort (I assume).

Comment: For the base case, does cor(dat$b1/dat$b2, dat$biomass)^2 give the correct R-squared for those two bands and that outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you might solve this kind of problem. I've made an assumption on how to calculate R2, but that's easily fixable if it's wrong.

First, we simulate some data

```
set.seed(123)
n_band=100
dat <- data.frame(matrix(runif(28*n_band),ncol=n_band))
colnames(dat) <- paste0("b",1:n_band)
dat$biomass <- rpois(28,10)
dat$nitrogen <- rpois(28,10)
dat$ID <- 1:28
```

Then, we observe that for each combination of band1, band2 and outcome we only need to store one number (R2). So, first we generate a dataframe containing all combinations of column names as string:

```
res <- expand.grid(paste0("b",1:n_band),paste0("b",1:n_band),outcome=c("biomass","nitrogen"))
```

Then we use apply to get the R2 for each row of res (thus each combination). As each row of res contains three column names, we can use those to access the original data.

```
#ignore warnings; correlation between similar variables is missing
res$R2 <- apply(res, MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x){
  return(cor(dat[,x[1]]/dat[,x[2]],dat[,x[3]])^2)
})
```

Then plotting is simple:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(res, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=R2))+
  geom_tile() +
  facet_grid(~outcome)
p1
```

Comment: Dear Heroka,

Thanks a lot for the propositions, they are certainly something I would not have been able to come up with all by myself and it is thus much appreciated. I used to use a different syntax for deriving the R2 values from a regression but your method seems just as good, if not better. I will look through your code in the coming days to enhance my understanding, and attempt to push my data through it. I will certainly let you know if I succeeded!

Thanks a lot, again.

Comment: I have updated the main post with respect to my progress so far. Fortunately I have managed to get my data to work with your coding quiet well, in addition to some graphical enhancements. All I am looking for now is a way to discretize my continuous R2 values to allow visualization through discrete classes. Besides I would like to be able to visually highlight the highest 5% of R2 values in the plot, or identify them manually. I have tried various tools today, but unfortunately without success. Any tips for the direction in which I should be looking instead, perhaps?